# Push_back into a vector of type class

Tags: c++, class, vector

Following is my code where I have to store contacts in a phonebook .

```
Class contact 
{

 private:
    string name;
    double number;
    string relation;
    int phonebookNum;
 public:
    Contact()
    Contact(Contact& temp) //copy constructor

    //set and get functions

};


 class phonebook
 {
  public:
    phonebook();
    void AddContact(contact temp);
    ~phonebook();

private:
    string name;

    vector <contact> vect;
    int peopleCount = 0;
};
```

The problem is that in my .cpp file when I declare my function for Add Contact

```
void phonebook::AddContact(contact temp)
{
    name = temp.getName();
    vect.push_back(temp);
    peopleCount++;
}
```

On reading the vect.push_back(temp) part, a separate tab opens up on my CodeBlocks by the name of : vector.tcc and shows an error in that file somewhere

How do I make a vector where I store my contacts and how do I access them ?

Comment: Post more details about error. Though it looks like its incorrect copy constructor that is causing problem. It should have 'const Contact &' param

Comment: Your class name is `Contact` but your `phonebook:AddContact` argument is `contact` (lower case "c").  You should work through such basic errors before posting here.  And list the full text of the error message.

Comment: C++ is case sensitive; "contact" and "Contact" are different names.

Comment: Did you initialize the vector in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Contact` class has an uppercase `C` while you pass a lowercase `contact` to the method `phonebook::AddContact`.

Declare your method like this

```
void phonebook::AddContact(Contact temp)
```

I would also suggest that you choose a way on how you name your classes.
Mixing up lower- and uppercase classes is not a good idea.